# GUI Programming isn't putting the Data into QTable Widget from SQL Query

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, qtablewidget, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm working on this coding project where we're to insert data from sql database into a qwidget table and I feel like my methodology

```py
    def show_list_1(self):
        name = "movie_api.db"
        conn, curs = open_db(name)
        query = f"""SELECT t.full_title, t.rating, p.rankUpDown
                        FROM movie_headlines t
                        INNER JOIN pop_movies p 
                        ON t.id = p.id"""
        curs.execute(query)
        result = curs.fetchall()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(data))
        conn.close()
```

This is what I'm working with and attached is what it looks like when run:

[image: GUI with Current Code]

Comment: `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)` before adding elements (or directly create the columns in Designer if you're using it). Note that you should properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: I did that and thank you! now it has the titles, but it's still for some reason skipping the rankUpDown and ratings. Cheers

Comment: If values are not strings, you cannot use them as argument in the constructor, since an `int` argument type is used for [other purposes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem). Create the item and then use `item.setText(str(data))` or `item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, data)`.